# Establishing GREG context root makes dashboard fail

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I have a greg instance with context root established (url access

```
https://host:9443/greg/carbon/admin/index.jsp
```

When I try to access the governance dashboard, all the gadgets show the same message.

```
Unable to retrieve spec for http://host:80/registry/resource/_system/config/repository/dashboards/gadgets/impact-analysis.xml. HTTP error 404
```

Note the gadget is trying to access to the root context without the `/greg/` prefix I have stablished.

Any help to solve this will be very appreciated.

Thank you
Pablo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is appearing when you set both HostName and WebContextRoot in carbon.xml.If you changed only the WebContextRoot this issue is not appearing.This is a known issue found in WSO2 GREG 4.1.1 and it is now fixed in trunk [1].

As a workaround can you keep the <HostName> entry as it is in carbon.xml and only change the web-context root and try.

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-11839

Thanks;

/Lalaji